# Pass items to a list to previous screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a search page that displays names with an add icon. When I press the add icon I want to pass the name to my previous screen that displays a list with names. I tried to do it as you can see down in my code but I have an error that my Athlete model doesn't have the constructor add. Can you help me figure out how to display the names in my list in previous screen? Thanks in advance!

My first screen that I display a list  with names:

```
class AthleteScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AthleteScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AthleteScreen> createState() => _AthleteScreenState();
}

class _AthleteScreenState extends State<AthleteScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  Future<List<Athlete>>? futureAthletebyTeamKey;
  final List<Athlete> _athlete = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'Athletes'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: [ 
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context)
                      .push<Athlete>(
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => const AddAthlete()))
                      .then((value) => setState(() {
                            if (value != null && value is Athlete) {
                              Athlete.add(_athlete[index].lastName, _athlete[index].firstName,_athlete[index].fatherName); //here is when I push to the page where the names that I want to add are displayed
                            }
                          }));
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                color: Colors.black,
                iconSize: 30.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(children: [
              FutureBuilder<List<Athlete>>(
                future: futureAthletebyTeamKey,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    List<Athlete> _athlete = snapshot.data;
                    return ListView.builder(  
                        itemCount: _athlete.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                            return CheckboxListTile(
                              title: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Flexible(
                                        child: Text(
                                          '${_athlete[i].lastName} ${_athlete[i].firstName}',
                                          
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                         
                  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    logger.e('${snapshot.error}');
                  }
                  return const Center(
                    heightFactor: 20,
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive(),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ]),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

My second screen where the names that I want to add in the list of my first page are displayed

```
class AddAthlete extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddAthlete({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddAthlete> createState() => _AddAthleteState();
}

class _AddAthleteState extends State<AddAthlete> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  Future<List<Athlete>>? futureSearchAthleteByName;

  @override
  void initState() {
    futureSearchAthleteByName =
        ApiService.searchAthletesByName(context) as Future<List<Athlete>>?;
    text = myController.text;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: const <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Add Athletes',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  child: Column(children: [
                    FutureBuilder<List<Athlete>>(
                      future: futureSearchAthleteByName,
                      builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          List<Athlete> _athlete = snapshot.data;
                          return ListView.builder(
                              itemCount: _athlete.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                if (myController.text == '') {
                                  return Container();
                                } else if (myController.text != '' &&
                                        _athlete[index]
                                            .lastName!
                                            .toLowerCase()
                                            .contains(myController.text
                                                .toLowerCase()) ||
                                    _athlete[index]
                                        .firstName!
                                        .toLowerCase()
                                        .contains(
                                            myController.text.toLowerCase())) {
                                  return Column(
                                    children: [
                                      ListTile(
                                        title: Column(
                                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                            ),
                                            Row(
                                              children: [
                                                Flexible(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    '${_athlete[index].lastName} ${_athlete[index].firstName}',
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                            Row(
                                              children: [
                                                Flexible(
                                                  child: Text(
                                                    '(${_athlete[index].fatherName})',
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ],
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        trailing: IconButton(
                                          icon: const Icon(
                                            Icons.add,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                          ),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            Navigator.pop(
                                                context,
                                                Athlete(
                                                    lastName: _athlete[index]
                                                        .lastName,
                                                    firstName: _athlete[index]
                                                        .firstName,
                                                    fatherName: _athlete[index]
                                                        .fatherName));
                                            print(_athlete[index].lastName);
                                            print(_athlete[index].firstName);
                                            print(_athlete[index].fatherName); \\here is when I pop the names in my previous screen
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                     
                                    ],
                                  );
                                
                                }
                              });
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          logger.e('${snapshot.error}');
                        }
                        return Container();
                      },
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was you I might do it in a different way

1. I add all the user id to the list on the second screen and pass the list to the second screen
2. in the first screen I call the API and get all the data by id and show it
   (when a user doesn't select any element don't call the API)

Comment: That's how i would do it too.

Comment: If I understand correctly I should make a new list in my second screen where I would add the name  that's selected and then pass this list in my first screen?

Comment: yes but not user names,used ids. it will be much more easier

Comment: but I have to display the name in the list in my first screen

Comment: Can you share with me an example of what you mean?

Comment: in your second screen, can you get the user ids?